# Why does Chrome add a pixel to my Div

Tags: html, styles, width, border

i have created a  which is 1010px long with a 5px border around it making it's length 1020, however, when i inspect the div in chrome, despite the fact the code still says it's with is 1010px and it's border is 5px it's actually 1021px

i can confirm that neither the left or right borders are adding a pixel as the div is supposed to house 5 separate images which each are 202px wide so all 5 should fit perfectly with no gaps but the first image as the slightest of gaps between it and the left border

i have had this work perfectly before but with tables, i'm currently redesigning the site to remove all the tables and replace them with divs while maintaining the exact same look

this is the code that creates the div

```
<div width="1010" align="center" style="border: 5px solid #9DBFFF; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
```

NOTE: yes i will move the style to a .css file after i got it working here first, another part of the redesign, removing all styles and putting them in .css files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the "width" property in the style attribute, like this:

```
<div align="center" style="border: 5px solid #9DBFFF; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:1010px;">
```

I inspected the div in Chrome and it's the exact width as specified in the css.

Comment: yeh, that worked now, curse browsers an their inability to render HTML the exact same way